# Clicking element in table based on condition on another element in the same row

Tags: java, python, selenium

I have the following example structure for a table I'm looking at:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="OddRow">
        <td class="TimeField">
        7:20 AM
        </td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_1" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField">
            <a id="basketControl_2_1" class="sr_AddToBasket">
                Add to Basket
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
        <td class="TimeField"></td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_2" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField"></td>
    </tr>
    ...OddRow
    ...EvenRow
</tbody>
```

What I would like to be able to do is click (using selenium) on the element with class "sr_AddToBasket" when the value in class "TimeField" is something I specify. Only one row of the table can ever have the specified time in a particular instance.

I'm really stuck as to how to go about this so any help will be greatly appreciated! If it helps I'm currently attempting this in python, but have some knowledge of java.

Comment: are you looking for the implementation or just the selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your structure looks like below after you add two more rows:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="OddRow">
        <td class="TimeField">
        7:20 AM
        </td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_1" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField">
            <a id="basketControl_2_1" class="sr_AddToBasket">
                Add to Basket
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
        <td class="TimeField"></td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_2" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="OddRow">
        <td class="TimeField"></td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_1" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
        <td class="TimeField">
        9:00 PM
        </td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_2" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField">
            <a id="basketControl_2_1" class="sr_AddToBasket">
                Add to Basket
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So, now say **you want to click on the 2nd link**, then please use the **below Java code**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='TimeField' and contains(text(),'9:00 PM')]/following-sibling::td/a[@class='sr_AddToBasket']")).click();
```

**You can replace the '9:00 PM' above with your value.**

Comment: Superb - this was exactly what I had in mind and with a couple of straightforward tweaks I've got this working in python: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='TimeField' and contains(text(),'7:20 AM')]/following-sibling::td/a[@class='sr_AddToBasket']").click()

Answer (score 0):

```
if driver.find_elements_by_css_xpath("//tr[@class='EvenRow']/td[@class='TimeField']").get_attribute("value")=="your value":
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='sr_AddToBasket']").click()
```

this `get_attribute` should return you the value you set and simple `if` condition matches the criteria of execution. Then next you find the link you want and click. I used `xpath` since it's helps us to identify element in a table easily.

Comment: Please explain why this code is doing the job requested. It helps the programmer to learn.

Comment: I think the xpath string //tr[@class='EvenRow'] is not needed. What if you need to click on an odd row?

Comment: Ya that can be excluded and the xpath will still work

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following: 
This question were answered here http://patch-recepteur.blogspot.com/2017/04/forum-clicking-element-in-table-based.html

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="OddRow">
        <td class="TimeField">
        7:20 AM
        </td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_1" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField">
            <a id="basketControl_2_1" class="sr_AddToBasket">
                Add to Basket
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
        <td class="TimeField"></td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_2" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="OddRow">
        <td class="TimeField"></td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_1" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="EvenRow">
        <td class="TimeField">
        9:00 PM
        </td>
        <td class="TextField"></td>
        <td id="Price_2_2" class="MoneyField"></td>
        <td class="LinkField">
            <a id="basketControl_2_1" class="sr_AddToBasket">
                Add to Basket
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```